# Swipe Gesture Recogniser not triggering?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swipe

I have a page view controller with five view controllers that get displayed.

I have tried adding these swipe gestures but they are not getting called?

```
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)];
swipeGestureRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeGestureRight.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight);
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRight];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)];
swipeGestureLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeGestureLeft.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft);
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeft];
```

Why arn't these being triggered and what can I do about it? My goal is to detect what direction the user swipes the page view controller.

Comment: Does the view you're adding them to have user interaction enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

- Set the delegate of your `UIGestureRecognizer` and
- Implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`:

  ```
  -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
  return YES;
  }
  ```
- Implement `shouldReceiveTouch`:

  ```
  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
  {
   return YES;
  }
  ```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but where exactly do I implement those two methods? I only have 1 page view controller class and I set the delegate and data source like this `self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;` I tried adding them just above my view did load method and my methods still arn't calling?

Comment: @CoolKatStudios : put it anywhere, but in same file.. if still its not working then there is something else issue...

Answer (score 0):

add gesture to self.view

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRight];
```

I hope it will work